# Struggling with net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING on production site of my Symfony2+PHP5.6+Apache 2.4.x app

Tags: apache, symfony

We face the "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" errors on our production site and cant find any working solution. StackOverflow is full of questions on this subject and we tried this and that but no working solution found. Our system is based on Symfony2+PHP5.6+Apache 2.4.x running on CentOS7.

Symptoms are that app is working fine when server starts ... but after some time the browser reports "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" errors and doest show certain pages (because they are loaded incompletely). Restarting apache fixes this for some time but it appears again soon. StackOverflow contains a lot of different hints that doesnt help us to understand the source of the problem. Can anyone give us some REAL hint here?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I found out that server sends incorrect content-lenght information to browser for some reasons and its the source of the error.

To adjust this I have enabled content gzipping by adding 'SetOutputFilter DEFLATE' to Apache config file see details here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html . This simple setting caused 'ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING' error to disappear and apps are working correctly for now. Whats more by gzipping the content the bandwidth dropped significantly.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a Controller in Drupal 8 (works for Symfony Framework as well) this solution worked for me:

```
$response = new Response($form_markup, 200, array(
  'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
));

$content = $response->getContent();
$contentLength = strlen($content);
$response->headers->set('Content-Length', $contentLength);

return $response;
```

Otherwise the response header 'Transfer-Encoding' got a value 'chunked'. This may be a problem for some browsers.